# Can't cast ReportImage to string in carrierwave Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, casting, carrierwave, image-uploading

Following ocumentation of carrierwave I added gem, generated ReportImage uploader, added

```
t.string :report_image, null: true, unique: true
```

to Report migration table and

```
mount_uploader :report_image, ReportImage
```

to Report model.

But I get `TypeError: can't cast ReportImage to string` when trying to create Report without ReportImage (nil)

Someone know how to fix it?

Comment: why did you take `null: true` remove that and try once, or have you seen about is anywhere?

Comment: still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Field cannot be unique. CarrierWave stores "no file" as empty string